# Visual Studio Code Intellisense Slow on Node proyect

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Currently I have this problem in big projects, either in node or python (django) projects.
And I noticed that vscode intellisense works very slow +7 seconds.

What I have tried to solve the problem.

1. Remove all extensions.
2. Disable all extensions.
3. Try the Insiders version.
4. Configure a basic jsconfig.json for the project.
5. Have the correct .gitignore.
6. Make a full clean install.

One thing I noticed, is that when I enter the project(just started the window, intellisense works fine) until it finishes loading the **"loading intellisense status"** that appears below and the slowness returns.

For which I believe that the problem comes from the fact that they are "big" projects.

My jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Same here, in an Angular project, it took me 3+ seconds to go to method definition within the same code file, whereas it used to be instant.